# Apply Regex.Escape() in my function that matches two strings

Tags: c#, regex

I have a function with 3 parameters. 1st parameter might contain a wild character("*"), the 2nd parameter is a normal string, while 3rd parameter is a wild character "*".  The main agenda of this function is to: Compare 1st two strings through Regex.Match() and returns:

```
    1. null, if 1st two strings do not match at all.
    2. Fetches and returns index from 2nd string.
    3. Returns empty if both strings match completely.
```

Function is as below:

```
static string GetIndex(string value, string stringToCompare, string wildCard)
{
                var match = Regex.Match(stringToCompare, string.Format("^{0}$", value.Replace(wildCard, @"(?<index>\d+)")), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                if (match == null || !match.Success) return null;

                return match.Groups["index"].Value;
}
```

Function works well for:

```
a. var a = GetIndex("PCONND*_DHEIGHT", "PCONND2_DHEIGHT", "*"); //Result:"2"
b. var a = GetIndex("CYL1_TYPE", "CYL1_TYPE", "*"); //Result: ""
```

But does not work for:

```
a. var a = GetIndex("CTOT(1)", "CTOT(1)", "*");
```

I got to know, Regex.Escape() can be used to escape characters but not able to apply here so that all my above cases could be successfully validated.

Comment: Thanks @James for the edit, I'll try to keep them in mind from next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to treat all `*` as numeric placeholders and treat all other chars as literal, you may still rely on a `Regex.Escape` method that adds a literal backslash in front of all chars that are considered some regex metacharacters, operators.

So, after using the method, all `*` will be escaped. Thus, just replace `\`+your `wildCard` to make sure you prepare the search pattern correctly:

```
static string GetIndex(string value, string stringToCompare, string wildCard)
{
    var match = Regex.Match(stringToCompare, string.Format("^{0}$", Regex.Escape(value).Replace($@"\{wildCard}", @"(?<index>\d+)")), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    if (match == null || !match.Success) return null;
    return match.Groups["index"].Value;
}
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/FqkyWx).

The part I modified is `Regex.Escape(value).Replace($@"\{wildCard}", @"(?<index>\d+)"))` where the `value` is escaped first, then all `\*` are replaced with `(?<index>\d+)`.

Answer (score 2):

The pattern `CTOT(1)` is using a capture group so will not match `CTOT(1)`.  You would need to escape the brackets to get the match `CTOT\(1\)`

Or alternatively you can check for complete matches using

`if (value.Equals(stringToCompare)) return "";`

Depending on your requirements you could possible remove the Regex.Match. This alternative method presumes that the wildcard is a only for a single digit value:

```
public string GetIndex(string value, string stringToCompare, char wildcard)
{
    bool stringsMatch = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < value.Length; i++)
    {
        //wild card match - return the value in stringTocompare
        if (value[i] == wildcard)
        {
            return stringToCompare[i].ToString();
        }
        else if (value[i] != stringToCompare[i]) //strings don't match
        {
            stringsMatch = false;
        }
    }

    return stringsMatch ? "" : null;
}
```

This is an example you would also need to handle for `stringToCompare` been shorter.

Comment: Thanks for the solution.